# 94 Corvette shutting down

Tags: chevrolet, fuel-system, stall, intermittent-problems, corvette

I have a 94 Corvettes that shut down after driving for a few minutes. I installed a new fuel pump. I think it’s the fuel relay. Only problem is I can’t locate where it is. I opened the passenger kick plate under the dash and I can see two relays the diagram shows there should be two groups of relays, one with two and the other with three. I don’t see the group of three. Do you have any suggestions

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Other than shutting off, why do you think it's fuel related? I can think of two other reasons the LT1 engine in your Vette would shut down like you describe. Have you put a fuel pressure gauge on the Schrader valve to see what the fuel pressure is doing? Does the car just cut out, or does it sputter to a halt? Does it start right back up after it quits?

Answer (score 1):

There is a relay box under the right side of the dash, the fuel pump relays are in there.

[image]